# All kind of errors while running apt-get update, GPG, BADSIG and more

Tags: apt, gnupg

Okay, I dont know what is going on and thats why I am writing here. I have seen many questions asked and the sollutions to the issues with gpg errors are either

```
sudo -i
apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
mv lists lists.old
mkdir -p lists/partial
apt-get clean
apt-get update
```

or

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys $KEY_FROM_ERROR
```

Okay I have tried both of these approaches to no success. I also keep getting inconsistetnt errors like:

```
W: GPG error: http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following   signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

or

```
E: Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/uk.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages.IndexDiff - open (2: No such file or directory)
```

or sometimes even doing it without errors. I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 Server on Virtualbox 4.1.8. I'm really puzzled here, so any assistance is really appreciated

Edit 1:

One more error meassage

```
W: GPG error: http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-security Release: Unknown error executing gpgv
```

Edit 2:

Some more, I want to make it perfectly clear, these come from sequential runnings of

```
apt-get update
```

one figures its natural to expect a consistent output when you run a program and don't change anything?

```
W: GPG error: http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release: The following  signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric-security Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: Failed to fetch http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-updates/Release.gpg  rename failed, No such file or directory ( -> /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/uk.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_oneiric-updates_Release.gpg). 

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the formating, the four spaces doesn't work, I don't know why. What a day...

Comment: You need a blank line before/after the code blocks with four spaces it seems. :)

Comment: cheers for that, I feel stupid now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your software sources Download mirror from main server to other, select the best server then let it update. Run `sudo -apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

If you still run into issues post back your print.

Comment: That did it, I updated the sources and it worked, thanks!

Comment: glad to be of help

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem, but none of the above methods worked for me, however, the following thing worked:

1. Opened Update Manager
2. Go to Settings
3. Click Ubuntu Software Tab
4. Un-check (disable) any options in Installable from CD-ROM/DVD  Box at the bottom of the menu

regards